# Uncaught TypeError : object is not a function error come when i try to document.index.submit();

Tags: form-submit, typeerror

```
<form role="form" class="register-form cf-style-1" name="index" action="#" method="post">
                    <div class="field-row">
                        <label>First Name: *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="le-input">
                        <label>Last Name: *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" class="le-input">
                        <label>Email: *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="le-input">
                        <input type="hidden" name="dbAction">
                        <label>Mobile Number: *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="mobileNumber" class="le-input">
                        <label>Create Password: *</label>
                        <input type="password" name="createPassword" class="le-input">
                        <label>Confirm Password: *</label>
                        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="le-input">
                    </div><!-- /.field-row -->

                    <div class="buttons-holder">
                        <button type="button" name="submit" onclick="validatePageData();" class="le-button huge">Sign Up</button>
                    </div><!-- /.buttons-holder -->
                </form>

<script>
    function validatePageData() {document.index.submit();
  }`
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and visit [ask]. I've edited your post so it shows what is in there but it makes little to no sense. Please [edit] your post and improve by asking an question, clearly state what is wrong, where and what you tried so far to resolve it.

Comment: See document object doesnot have a method such as index. So whenever you tries to invoke an undefined function, it gives you this error.

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms[name ="index"].submit()` should work.